# Member function calls inside a class constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, member-functions

I am having some definitions problems inside my class:

```
class Test{

protected:

    int a;
    int *b;
    Teste() {}

public:

    int getA() {return a;}
    int getB() {if (b) return *b; else return 0;}
    bool isB() {if(b) return true; else return false;}
    Test(int a1, int b1): a(a1) {b = new int(b1);}
    Test(const Test& test) {
        if (test.isB())
        this->b = new int(test.getB());
        this->a = test.getA();
    }

};
```

I get the following error message:

"Invalid arguments 'Candidates are bool isB()'"

and

"Invalid arguments 'Candidates are bool getB()'"

What is the problem?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare your getter functions const to be able to access them through the const Test& test you have.

```
...
int getA() const { return a; }
int getB() const { if (b) return *b; else return 0; }
bool isB() const { if(b) return true; else return false; }
...
```